# Knockout JS data-binding on Virtual Element inside template is not working on Windows 8.1 Cordova Application

Tags: windows, cordova, knockout.js

I am using following code for virtual DOM element data binding in my Cordova Application. This code is working fine for IE 11,  Android and iOS but not working on Windows 8.1 Cordova App

If I use regular DOM element binding it's working fine for Windows as well. But my requirement is to use Virtual DOM Element Binding.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Prooduct</title>

    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="libs/knockout/knockout.js"></script>

    <script type="text/html" id="product-template">

    <ul>
        <!-- ko foreach: productArray-->
        <li><span data-bind="text: productName"></span><br /></li>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <h4>Product List</h4>

    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'product-template'}"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ProductViewModel() {
            this.productArray = ko.observableArray([
               { productName: 'Milk' },
               { productName: 'Oil' },
               { productName: 'Butter' }]);
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new ProductViewModel());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use the same `foreach` on ul which works like virtual stuff in your scenario .

Comment: @supercool I cant do like that, I have already mentioned in my question

Comment: yes i seen that now but can i ask why you are more inclined to use container less . as i see the above scenario is simple .

Comment: Its not actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code produces a JavaScript-error: "productName not found" under Windows 8.1. I assume it is a race condition between the script block in the header and body.

The following code does not produce this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>KnockoutTemplate</title>
    <script src="scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Product List</h4>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'product-template'}"></div>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>

    <script type="text/html" id="product-template">
        <ul>
            <!-- ko foreach: productArray-->
            <li><span data-bind="text: productName"></span><br /></li>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </ul>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ProductViewModel() {
            this.productArray = ko.observableArray([{
                productName: 'Milk'
            }, {
                productName: 'Oil'
            }, {
                productName: 'Butter'
            }]);
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new ProductViewModel());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**I would strongly recommend to put the JavaScript into an external file as I wrote in the first answer.**

Answer (score 2):

I tested it successful with cordova CLI 4.3.1/Visual Studio 2015/Windows 10 and Windows 8.1(remote debugging):

index.js:

```
// and then run "window.location.reload()" in the JavaScript Console.
$(document).ready(function () {

    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.

    };

    function onPause() {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    };

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    };

    function AppViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.productArray = ko.observableArray([
        { productName: 'Milk' },
        { productName: 'Oil' },
        { productName: 'Butter' }]);

        self.removeProduct = function () {
            self.productArray.remove(this);
        }
    };
    var vm = new AppViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>testios</title>

    <!-- testios references -->
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>List of product</h2>
    <hr />
    <ul>
        <!-- ko foreach: productArray -->
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: productName"></span>  <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeProduct">Remove </a>
        </li>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Initial window:**

[image: Initial window]

**After click on Remove Oil:**

[image: After click on remove Oil]

Did you use the latest knockout-3.3.0.js?

In my opinion you could also test it with IE without cordova, because it is the same browser engine:

http://jsfiddle.net/k7x7a6q9/

Tested in IE11 and MS Edge 20.10240.16384.0 under Windows 10

A good way to find the root cause, is to look in the DOM-Explorer, to see what is happening. It is automatically open, when you start debugging or you can open it by typing "DOM" in the Quick Launch field during debugging in the top right of Visual Studio:

[image]

...and set a breakpoint in JavaScript, to verify if the click event is thrown:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bjoerg. in my case same code is working fine in IE. But for windows 8.1 cordova app its not working. I am using  Knockout version 3.1. Will test with 3.3

Comment: @Shamse: I add Visual Studio screenshots I made during a Windows 8.1 remote debugging session. Does the HTML update when clicking "remove"? Is the JavaScript function "self.removeProduct" called?

Comment: But the same code inside a template is not working for Cordova app. I tested it with knockout js 3.3 its not working. Its working fine for IE 11 on Windows 8.1

Comment: What exactly is not working? 1. No <li> elements showing up? 2. The "Remove" clicks are not working? 3. Anything else? - By the way, you are missing <!DOCTYPE html> in your HTML.

Comment: And try to put the "<!-- ko foreach: productArray -->" in the <body> part and separate the Javascript part, as I done in my example. So you could be sure everything is loaded correctly. I did try to use your code and get JavaScript and Knockout errors in Visual Studio.

Comment: Same code is working in android and ios  also in IE 11 but in windows 8.1 cordova app getting java script error.

Comment: Ok, I reproduce the JS-error: "productName not found" -> It would be much better if you put this error in your question, so one could help you better :) I create another answer with the solution.